# Pass Button Name from XAML to ViewModel using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In my `XAML`, I have defined a button as such:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Width="Auto">
            <Button Width="200" Height="300" Click="SelectMovie_Click" >
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate >
                        <Image Source="{Binding image}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:UniqueNameBehavior ID="{Binding id}"/>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Button>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I use the `Behaviour` to dynamically assign a name to my button.

```
public class UniqueNameBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    public UniqueNameBehavior() : base() { }

    public String ID
    {
        get { return (String)this.GetValue(IDProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(IDProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();            
        //Assign unique name to the associated element
        AssociatedObject.Name = "movie" + ID;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IDProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                             "ID", typeof(String), 
                                                             typeof(UniqueNameBehavior));
}
```

When this button is clicked, I would like to pass this `Name` to my `ViewModel`.

This is my `Behind-Code`

```
private void SelectMovie_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // _moviePanelVM is an instance of my ViewModel
   _moviePanelVM.GetSelectedMovieDetails();
}
```

So I understand I could retrieve the button name here and pass it to the `ViewModel` but I feel this might not be the right way to do this if using the `MVVM` model.

Could anyone please suggest as to how I might achieve this the correct way?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a **Command** in your ViewModel: For example the Commands Section here could help: [Implementing the MVVM Pattern Using the Prism Library 5.0 for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx) .

And add a parametrized Command with the help of the Prism library and as the parameter you commit the **Name** of your button (Internet is full of help). And bind the command to your button.

Answer (score 0):

Use command parameters in XAML file. This is simple sintax to pass object with button  "CommandParameter={Binding senderObject}" add this at the end of the button tag.

Access the same in the

```
private void SelectMovie_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   String buttonId = sender as String;
   // _moviePanelVM is an instance of my ViewModel
   _moviePanelVM.GetSelectedMovieDetails();
}
```